# Delete duplicate mails in Exchange 2010

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

We had an issue with our Exchange 2010 outlook or server and for some reasons we had all our user receiving internally and externally duplicated mails with the same message ID.

I know there are third party software we can buy and we are not allowed to do so.

Is there any code we can run on PowerShell to delete all the duplicated mails on the all mailboxes on the server?

thanks

Mes

Answer (score 0):

There is this script (https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Removing-Duplicate-Items-f706e1cc) which suggested by Microsoft, but you must specify the user mailbox.

Put this script to that destination

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\1.2

After that use this command:

```
.\Remove-DuplicateItems.ps1 
    -Mailbox "user@domain.com" 
    -Type All 
    -Impersonation 
    -DeleteMode HardDelete 
    -Mode Full 
    -Verbose
```

You can change the delete mode to 'SoftDelete' or 'MoveToDeletedItems' etc.